When I edit UnityPackage and Export & Import, I get "The type or namespace name 'xxxxx' could not be found"
I'm a beginner with Unity.
I imported a UnityPackage distributed on GitHub into my scene.
There were no errors when I imported the UnityPackage distributed on GitHub.

After making a small edit to the code in that file, I exported it from Asset/Export Package with the name "Test.unitypackage".

I didn't add any new files, just lightly edited the existing code.
When I tried to import the UnityPackage I edited and exported into a new project scene, over 400 errors appeared.

Most of the errors seem to be related to namespaces, like the following:
The type or namespace name 'xxxxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


In such a case, what steps might I have gotten wrong?

you are missing something it depends on

How do I export all my dependencies? I have right clicked on the Assets folder and tapped “Export package” and then made sure “include dependencies” is checked but I am getting an error.

wrong kind of dependancies.. so, the package dependancies you have in that is for example if youe export a prefab, the scripts, materials, models, animations... NOT the unity packages such as textmesh pro, tilemap etc.
